# Add custom attribute variable to order confirmation e-mail template

Tags: magento

I have created several custom attributes for my products.
I have some that need to be added to the email that the costumer receives when he places an order. 
Currently I found that I can edit the mail template in the backend and 'app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml'.

**How to access object variables in e-mail templates and what is the proper syntax for item custom attributes?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several possibilities (this being Magento).

The template *app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml* you mentioned is the wrapper for all the items in the order. The individual items are rendered by separate templates. Most of the time that is *app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml*, but other product types can use different ones, e.g. order items for bundled products use *...template/bundle/email/order/items/order/default.phtml*.

Inside the templates you are not working with `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` model instances, but with `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item` instances. These items have different attributes then product attributes.
If you want to have your custom product attributes **always** to be available on the `sales/order_item` instances, you will need to add them to the entity.
During the checkout process, also set them on the `sales/quote_item` entity and them copy them over to the order items using the appropriate fieldsets in the configuration (see `global/fieldsets`in *Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml* for an example.

**If** the products still exist in the catalog, they can be loaded including all attributes using

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderItem->getProductId();
```

Or, to fetch all product models for all order items at once (slightly more efficient):

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addIdFilter($orderItems->getColumnValues('product_id'))
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('list', 'of', 'your', 'custom', 'attributes'));
```

Of course, this will mean additional queries as compared to the first solution of adding the same attributes to the order item entity.
Also be aware that once a product is deleted it won't be loadable in this way any more.